# Does filter preserve list ordering?

Tags: python, filter

Say you call the "filter" function on a list, and you use this to find all elements that satisfy a certain property.  Are the elements in the output list guaranteed to be in the same order that they were in the input list?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. Lists are ordered iterables, and the `filter` generator reads each item in, one at a time in that order. Therefore, it will yield output in order.

```
>>> example = list(range(10))
>>> list(filter(lambda n: n % 2, example))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex!  Which other data structures count as "ordered iterables?"  I know hash tables probably don't.  Are lists the only ones?

Comment: @Jessica Tuples, strings, OrderedDict, Queue, deque, and everything that implements `collections.abcs.Sequence`.

Comment: Lists, strings, tuples etc. Unordered ones include dictionaries or sets, which are in arbitrary order, or iterators such as `range` because we don't have the full thing in memory at one time.

Answer (score 13):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for `filter`:

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))`

As the equivalent generator expression would preserve order, `filter` is guaranteed to preserve it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  I looked at those docs but I didn't know how generators worked so I didn't realize they preserved order.

Comment: @Jessica Yeah, it's a bit of a rabbit hole; in the end, `filter`, generator expressions, list comprehensions, etc. rely on the `__iter__` method of an object, which iterates through each element in order, if the object is ordered like e.g. a `list` or `tuple`.